# Spring MVC jsp c:if tag doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<!-- jQuery -->
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>

        <c:if test="${error}">
            <script>
                alert("You must have something...");
            </script>
        </c:if>



</body>
</html>
```

#### jsp file has

```
<c:if test="${error}">
    <script>
        alert("You must have something...");
    </script>
</c:if>
```

#### spring controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample/board.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateBoard(@ModelAttribute HistoryBoard historyBoard) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect");

    mv.addObject("error", true);

    return mv;
}
```

and it make url `http://localhost:8080/test/board/board.do?error=true`

but `c:if` tag doesn't work

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</c:if>
```

`c:if` not empty doesn't work too.

how to fix this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a parameter, not a scope variable.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</c:if>
```